# xorg-x11-drv-intel system failure, Intel Iris Xe, I7 1165 G7

Tags: fedora, intel

I've installed Fedora 35 on my new laptop (Asus x513 i7 1165g7)
and, since I changed from Windows 11 to f35,
this system failure always appears when starting my system. 
The backtrace says:

```
WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 387 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_tc.c:878 intel_tc_port_init+0x229/0x230 [i915]
Modules linked in: i915(+) i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper nvme nvme_core cec hid_multitouch crct10dif_pclmul drm crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel serio_raw i2c_hid_acpi vmd wmi i2c_hid video pinctrl_tigerlake ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler fuse
CPU: 2 PID: 387 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 5.16.20-200.fc35.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X513EAN_X513EAN/X513EAN, BIOS X513EAN.201 05/31/2021
RIP: 0010:intel_tc_port_init+0x229/0x230 [i915]
Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 70 6e 43 f7 48 c7 c1 40 78 4f c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 75 6a 51 c0 48 89 c6 e8 97 6c 82 f7 <0f> 0b e9 59 ff ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 53 89 f3 48 83 ec 08
RSP: 0018:ffffb69e80577ae0 EFLAGS: 00010282
RAX: 0000000000000031 RBX: ffff9d77c7874000 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffffb8635b25 RDI: 00000000ffffffff
RBP: 0000000000000002 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffb69e80577920
R10: ffffb69e80577918 R11: ffffffffb8f462e8 R12: ffff9d77c1737510
R13: ffff9d77c7874f90 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: 00000000ffffffff
FS:  00007fa100b42b40(0000) GS:ffff9d7937680000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 000055cef5b0ebc8 CR3: 0000000102bce003 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
```

The reason:

```
WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 387 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_tc.c:878 intel_tc_port_init+0x229/0x230 [i915]
```

cmdline:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-5.16.20-200.fc35.x86_64 root=UUID=ef22d715-7597-4a9a-b9a0-71a8f4ffc672 ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet
```

package:
kernel-core-5.16.20-200.fc35

I'm new to Linux, so, I would be very happy if someone could help me! 
I've Googled this topic many times, and didn't find any answer, only for Nvidia GPUs, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Curious if you found an answer to this as I'm encountering the same problem as well and I'm also very new to Linux too. Through all my digging I can only think that there was either

1. A poor boot
2. Intel drivers need to be updated but are proprietary in a way so there's no way to fix it and to just ignore it or boot back to Windows. Wine also does not allow to usage of the .exe files for the drivers so it's been pretty useless.
3. The Intel drivers can be updated or at least there's something there missing and the machine is flagging it
4. It's something I can't even think of or a Fedora issue.
   Not only that, but I haven't even been able to boot back to Windows. I've tried very hard but I can't figure it out as it says there are no drivers to install to so I'm kind of stuck with a broken Linux. Was going to ask any and all support like Windows, HP, or take it to a PC place.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420715)

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. If you are experiencing issues, please ask a question to get help.